# Logstash send only json

Tags: json, logstash, logstash-grok

iam sendding this log via logstash

```
2017-02-27T13:00:07+01:00    test    {"createdAt":"2017-02-27T13:00:07+0100","cluster":"undefined","nodeName":"undefined","nodeIP":"10.11.11.50","clientIP":"10.11.11.72","customerId":1,"identityId":332,"appType":"admin","eventGroup":"education","eventName":"insert","eventData":{"education_insert":{"type":"course","data":{"education_id":2055,"education":{"id":2055,"customer_id":1,"creator_id":332,"type":"course","status":"new","is_featured":false,"enroll_deadline":null,"complete_deadline":null,"count_view":0,"count_like":0,"meta_title":"test Course - progress","meta_description":"test Course - progress","discoverable":"everyone","progress_max":0,"instructor_ids":[332],"tag_ids":[135],"discoverable_group_ids":[],"category_ids":[14],"audits":null,"instructors":null,"creator":null,"lessonGroups":null,"categories":null},"duration":"quick"}}},"scopeType":"education","scopeId":"2055"}
```

how can i remove `2017-02-27T13:00:07+01:00` and `test.app.event`

Comment: Go to the line where you say "send datetime, then test, then json", and remove the first 2 items :)
For a more detailed answer you might want to add some details to what you are doing, as it's near impossible to debug this :)

Comment: i need send only json data but i dont know how to remove frist 2 items in logstash using filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this and worked for me :) thx for help

```
input { kafka { bootstrap_servers=>"localhost:9092" topics=>"test"}}
filter{
grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\t%{GREEDYDATA:topic}\t%{GREEDYDATA:json}" }
  }
  json {
     source => "json"
     remove_field => ["timestamp","topic","json","message","@version","@timestamp","tags"]
  }
 }
output{ elasticsearch {hosts=>["127.0.0.1:9200"] document_type=>"app_stats" index=>"test"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `grok` extract the json portion of the message and then use the `json` filter to convert the extracted json into the event.  Finally you'll need to remove any fields using `mutate` that you don't want in your final event (for example, `message`).

Comment: In grok i have to use "match" ?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use a **regex** pattern in order to only get the `json`. The `regex` pattern should be within your *patterns* file:

The pattern could look like:

```
REQUIREDDATA {([^}]*)}([^}]*)([^}]*)}}}([^}]*)} <-- this extracts only your json part
```

The regex [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/UGJiuF/1) which was tested.

Thereafter you could use the pattern within your *grok* **match**:

```
grok {
    patterns_dir => ["/pathto/patterns"]
    match => { "message" => "^%{REQUIREDDATA:new}" }            
}
```

Now the message only has the `JSON` part from your log line, hence you could push them to ES via `logstash` now. The above is just a sample, so that you could reproduce.

Hope it helps!